# Problems with acts_as_votable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to implement rating system with gem 'acts_as_votable', but have some error:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes for ActsAsVotable::Vote: votable, voter, vote_scope

I did everything like they recommend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably still using the protected_attributes gem. In rails 4 strong parameters are used for whitelisting attributes. It would be best if you could make the transition from attr_accessible to strong parameters.

Anyway, this link is an example of someone with the same problem: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable/issues/56

Comment: Thanks! Changing code to use strong paramets instead of 'protected_attributes' gem solved problem :)